# How to handle no data in JqPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Is there a best approach to handle "no data" with JqPlot?

Assuming that I'm consuming json data with an ajax call, and eventually no data is available, eg:

```
[['North'][0],['South'][0],['East'][0],['West'][0]]
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Shouldn't JQPlot return an empty plot if there is no data to render, instead of throwing an exception? To me this is a valid state, not an error ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I always have a condition that I check in my `AJAX` function, which checks for no results. Then if no results happen I set a chart so that it looks empty. For this reason `var data = [[null]]` should do, where `data` is a parameter of `jQuery.jqplot('chart', data, {})`. The value of `data` might be dependant on a type of chart, thus I tested it for line, bar and pie chart and it works fine.

Optionally you could also hide legend and maybe other parts of the plot. For me just setting the `data` and legend is always enough.

Answer (score 2):

`var data = [null];` will trigger errors in console and stop JS script execution further.
The better solution will be to use the following.

```
var data = [''];
jQuery.jqplot('chart', data, {});
```

This will print any subsequent graphs and/or continue JS scripts execution with no errors in FF/Chrome/IE consoles. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how this works for you--it will fail `$.isArray(data[0]) == false || data[0].length == 0` in https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/blob/1870d3beddd96dc62b948196c4eb9dfd5833e763/src/jqplot.core.js#L2063

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the opposite to Rahi's answer (maybe the missing double brackets around null was the issue), meaning I agree with Boro;

This works: `var data = [[null]];`
and this: `var data = [''];` generates an error, one time no matter if I have multiple charts or just one with no data.

I'm running jqPlot 1.0.9

The error I get is: `Uncaught Error: No data specified` from the condition in the jqPlot script

```
if (0 == this.noDataIndicator.show)
                    throw new Error("No data specified");
```